# Two matrices such that AB=B and BA=A yield collinear projections?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, projection-matrices

$A$ and $B$ are two matrices such that $AB=B$ and $BA=A$. For vector $z$, let $x=Az$ and $y=Bz$. Can we show two vectors $x$ and $y$ are in the same direction? Is there any special condition required to yield this conclusion, such as $A$ and $B$ must be projection matrices?

Comment: The conditions $AB=B$ and $BA=A$ imply that $A,B$ are square matrices of the same dimension. Also we get
$$
B^2=B(AB)=(BA)B=AB=B\\
A^2=A(BA)=(AB)A=BA=A
$$
so $A,B$ _are_ projection matrices.

Comment: @quasi Thanks. So can we conclude $x$ and $y$ in the same direction?

Comment: Note: the statement in my earlier comment does not hold

Comment: @Chang we can show that there exists some $z$ for which $x$ and $y$ are parallel.  However, the statement can only hold for **every** vector $z$ if $A = B$.

Answer (score 0):

You want that $A,B$ have a common eigenvector.

It suffices that $AB=B$ OR $BA=A$.

For example,assume that $AB=B$, that is, $(A-I)B=0$. Then $A-I,B$ have a common eigenvector and, then, $A,B$ have a common eigenvector.